# How can one permanently remove parts of history edits on MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I got a file uploaded to the wiki that is usually edited by a certain team.  As an IT support person I got in to try a few things out with the file, when the team had trouble.  As result, I have made an edit, and the team later rolled the edit back.

Problem:  on `File:filename.pdf` under `File History` it now says things like

- current [date] [size] [team] reverted
- revert [date] [size] [me] test edit
- revert [date] [size] [team] comment

**Question**

The team wants to erase my edit and their revert from history altogether as if it had never happened.

How can I do that?

I have access to raw database if needed, but hoping there is a simple way.

Comment: Are you talking about [MediaWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki) (a commonly used wiki software) or about [Wikimedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikimedia_Foundation) (an organization dedicated to the wiki-based proliferation of knowledge)? In your tags, you include the former, but in your title, you mention the latter.

Comment: MediaWiki (software)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you can live with erasing the whole revision history of the page, you can use the maintenance script [`DeleteOldRevisions.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:DeleteOldRevisions.php):

   `php maintenance/deleteOldRevisions.php --delete PAGEID`

2. Another option is to enable the [**RevisionDelete**](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:RevisionDelete) function. This will enable you, as a sysop, to hide specific (non-current) revisions from ordinary users:
   [image]

Edit: [Tgr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/323407/tgr) points out below that it is still possible to see that revisions hidden this way *has been hidden*.

Comment: thanks.  I can't delete entire history, it needs to stay there.  option 2 looks like a better choice for me.

Comment: Note that there is absolutely no way to delete the current revision, so first you must revert and re-revert until you are happy with the content and edit summary of the current revision. Also note that DeleteOldRevisions.php will actually delete all old revisions from the database, while most other solutions just hide them (to some degree). RevisionDelete, with the default configuration, will actually just make it unaccessible - it will end up [looking like this](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:RevisionDelete#/media/File:RevDelete_isn%27t_subtle_(2).png).

Comment: As for now the script DeleteOldRevisions.php does not work. More info at https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T271635

Answer (score 2):

There should be a delete link next to the old versions of the image in the history section of the file page (if you are logged in as an administrator), just use that.

[image: position of delete button]